How much time do I need at Salzburg Hbf to change from a train to a bus?
I will be traveling from Feldkirch to Salzburg Hbf on the RJX 869 and will arrive at Salzburg at 17:02 (if the train has no delay). After that I want to catch bus 150 to Bad Ischl, which leaves at 17:15.
Do you think I have enough time to alight from the train, purchase the bus ticket, and go to platform F to catch the 17:15 bus?

Where do you get the 7 minutes from? Your train is at least scheduled to arrive in Salzburg 17:02 and the next bus departs 17:15.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo the train is quite often late though.

You can buy the ticket online, that would probably help a lot. Worst case, next bus is 30 minutes later.

The station layout is very straight forward: http://karteplan.com/osterreich/stadt/salzburg/salzburg-hbf-plan.jpg. Even from the farthest platform, it should only be a couple of minutes to walk to the bus stops. I can't tell you about getting a ticket though; if you can get one in advance, that'd be the safest option.

Relevant: RJX 869 is often delayed, see https://www.zugfinder.net/de/zug-RJX_869. To salzburg hbf last 10 days have had delays of 0, 3, 4, 2, 7, 2, 62, 12, 1, 7, 7 minutes respectively.
